# How to change TextViews in OnSensorChanged within a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-sensors

I'm trying to build a simple Fragment which reads out an environment sensor and change a TextView when the environment data is changed. Unfortunately, the number isn't displayed at all.

Should I approach this problem differently, or am I doing something wrong?

Fragment code:
https://github.com/Obdamned/PhoneStatus/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/casob/phonestatus/fragment/SensorViewFragment.java

(Wasn't allowed to post a code block of this amount of lines)

Comment: `the number isn't displayed at all`... which number? Do you find any error? It's not the simple case of two xml layouts for your activity, one portrait and one landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only time you're updating the `TextView`'s text is in `#setLux` which is only called in `#onCreateView`. You're setting the text to `mLightString` which is initially null so we can assume the first sensor value isn't available until after `#onCreateView` is called. Change line 118 to `mLux.setText(String.valueOf(light))` and that should see it updating real time. As for the initial value maybe you want to have `mLightString` start with a default value or message or something while the sensor data is loading.

Comment: This did it for me. I overlooked the problem and it's solution.